# Is JDBC the only option to connect to aws hosted rds from aws lambda function

Tags: jdbc, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-rds, amazon-rds-proxy

Like the title asks, im wondering if the only way of connecting to my aws hosted rds through aws lambda function in java is through a jdbc connection?

Does the aws sdk provide a way of doing this, querying the data and returning results without the need for jdbc?

I've looked through the aws api documentation but nothing is jumping out at me in terms of making a connection through the aws sdk alone, it seems to provide functions on more admin type tasks. .

The reason  I ask is in the interest of speed, the jdbc connection takes a few seconds for a connection, but thought if the aws sdk could connect it may be quicker?

Comment: Use a connection pool. That will amortize away the cost of indivudual connections asymptotically to zero.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the kind of database you use there are different options.
If you want to reduce the connection latency, you could look into using [RDS proxy](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/), which will act as a reverse-proxy in from of the database instances and has a couple of connections ready for you to use.
It's also optimized to let you quickly establish connections through JDBC to it.

If you use Aurora Serverless, you might be able to use the Data API, which uses the AWS SDK to make requests to the database over HTTP. You can find more information on that in the docs: [Using the Data API for Aurora Serverless](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html).

You can also always use connection pooling in your lambda functions, which will at least make warm lambdas more performant but doesn't help you with cold starts.